ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column for APEX Oracle INSERT INTO TABLE
Trying to get this script to run on my APEX Oracle workspace. The attempt is to make random integers/varchars and put them into the table FIRST. This is the current script I am using:

CREATE TABLE FIRST
(
ROW_UNIQUE_SEQ_ID NUMBER(20), 
FIXED_ALPHA VARCHAR(5),
COUNTER NUMBER(1),
RAN_ALPHA VARCHAR(8),
RAN_INT NUMBER(1),
FIXED_INT NUMBER(1),
CREATED_UNIQUE_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(2) 
)
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;

INSERT INTO FIRST(ROW_UNIQUE_SEQ_ID,FIXED_ALPHA,COUNTER,RAN_ALPHA,RAN_INT,FIXED_INT,CREATED_UNIQUE_TIMESTAMP)
SELECT level, 'GGGGG' AS FIXED_ALPHA,
level AS COUNTER,
DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('u',8) AS RAN_ALPHA,
DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 10) AS RAN_INT,
5 AS FIXED_INT,
LOCALTIMESTAMP(2)+level/24/60/60 FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <=10000000;
COMMIT;



Every time I run it, I receive the error message on the INSERT INTO statements:

INSERT INTO FIRST(ROW_UNIQUE_SEQ_ID,FIXED_ALPHA,COUNTER,RAN_...   ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

I tried running the script in APEX, I expected all the large values to be inserted into the table.

Running that select statement shows exactly what is going on:

Column RAN_INT does have precision - but it's defined as NUMBER(1). Docs state: DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE produces numbers in [0,1) with 38 digits of precision..
Solution:
Replace
DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 10) AS RAN_INT, with FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 10)) AS RAN_INT,
However, there is another issue. The column COUNTER is also defined as NUMBER(1) so it is will only accept numbers 1 through 9 and error out with that same error for the 10th row.
Solution:
Create the table with datatypes NUMBER instead of NUMBER(1)
Also, Oracle does not advise using data type VARCHAR. Use VARCHAR2 instead.
